# how to chain multiple jQuery clicks when second click must wait for first click ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, click

I have a bunch of elements that act as buttons for users to click on.  In certain circumstances, I want to force click the buttons myself.  I have added click event handlers to all these elements and they work fine.

The problem is when I want to force click two of the buttons in succession like:

```
jQuery('#spProfileTab-some-button').click();
jQuery('#spProfileMenu-another-button').click();
```

this doesnt work however, because the click handler for the second one isnt bound until the ajax for the first click handler completes.

Basically need to chain them or have the second wait for first to complete, but havent found the right syntax yet.  any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery trigger ,

please see the documentation here

http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the second click from the callback of the ajax.  So if you are using load()for example you would be

```
$('selector').load('content',function(){$(otherselecter).click()});
```

You dont have a chain/queue there because the semicolon really makes that 2 separate commands.  So just keep that in mind.

Comment: yeah I know it wasnt a chain. wasnt meant to be. couldnt get them on two separate lines for some reason.

Comment: lol. sorry, first post here. hit enter for newline and submitted comment. the problem is in normal situation (ie user click on element), I dont want the first click handler to fire the second one.

Answer (score 0):

So the sequence of events you want is 1) some-button is clicked, 2) the AJAX in the click handler some-button binds a click handler to another-button, 3) that click handler is called?

In that case you need to trigger 3) at the end of the AJAX success handler for 2, i.e.

```
$('some-button'.click( function() {
  $.ajax( {... success: function() {
    ...
    $('another-button').click(another-button-handler);
    $('another-button').click();
  }
});
```

Because the AJAX call is asynchronous that's how you guarantee that the click() call to another-button is handled after the AJAX completes and the new click handler is bound.

Comment: the problem being that in the general sense, when first button is clicked by user, I dont want the second button action.  only want it in the special case where I want to click the second button but have to click the first to run the ajax and get the second button bound.hope that make sense

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have a handler on the first button that you only want to run once. So you could also put some jQuery in the success callback that unbinds that click handler from the first button.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I've misunderstood your question, by the sound of it the click handler on the first element is calling an AJAX function (perhaps jQuery's `get`, `post` or `load`)?

If that's the case, you should be able to simply trigger the click on your second element in the callback function, for example something like this:

```
$.post("somepage.php", function(data) {
    //Successful AJAX call
    $('#spProfileMenu-another-button').click();
});
```

I'm assuming your the click event on the first element is something like this:

```
$('#spProfileTab-some-button').click(function() {
    //AJAX call as above
});
```

Comment: as you can tell, not a jQuery expert.

Comment: @Mr Papa - This comment editor isn't designed for multiple line comments, but you can use
Shift+Enter

Comment: thanks! yes, the event handler on the 'first' button (actually a series of buttons) uses ajax load.

it loads a series of new buttons and binds them.  think of it as a menu and then sub menus. not really what it is, but hopefully gets the point across.

in essence, what I want to do is go directly to the second set of buttons (or sub menu) without user interaction. so I dont want the click handler for the first button to always call the second one.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably use the deferred.done() method as explained here: http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/

In your "force click" example, you'd probably call the .done() method where you've created your AJAX call.

So like...

```
$.get("ajax.php").done(function() { 
    $('another-button').click();
});
```